# Reading from file in Python, weird error

Tags: python, file

```
 f = open("‪C:\Users\aleed_000\Desktop\dis.txt","r")
 print (f.read())
 f.close()
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't read from my file named dis.txt? When I tried to run it, it says error, and then highlights the open paren. I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Please post the whole traceback.

Answer (score 4):

Use a raw string or escape each `'\'` by prefixing another `'\'` to it:

because `C:\Users\aleed_000\Desktop\dis.txt` is actually interpreted like this:

```
>>> print ("‪C:\Users\aleed_000\Desktop\dis.txt") # '\a' gets escaped
C:\Usersleed_000\Desktop\dis.txt
```

Raw string:

```
>>> print (r"‪C:\Users\aleed_000\Desktop\dis.txt")  #notice the r at the start
C:\Users\aleed_000\Desktop\dis.txt
```

Escape each `'\'`:

```
>>> print ("‪C:\\Users\\aleed_000\\Desktop\\dis.txt")
C:\Users\aleed_000\Desktop\dis.txt
```

Comment: Or escape every \ character: `"‪C:\\Users\\aleed_000\\Desktop\\dis.txt"`. Each solution works fine :)

Comment: When I use the first piece of code (the example print code) I get SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier, when is of course not what you got

Comment: @user2317745 Please post that in the question body.