# File Not Found Error Python 3.5

Tags: python

The code below gives me `FileNotFoundError`. I'm running Python 3.5.1 in Jupyter Notebook (installed with Anaconda package). The file `test.txt` exists in the described folder with a simple text string in it.

```
  myfile = open(r'C:\Users\324706\test.txt', 'r')
```

[image: FileNotFoundError]

Comment: You have made a mistake somewhere. The file does not exist, otherwise you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: I right-clicked on the file and selected properties: it shows location as C:\Users\324706.

Comment: You might want to try `import os` and `os.listdir("c:\\Users\\324706")`

Comment: Check these questions: [File not found Error in reading text in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262734/file-not-found-error-in-reading-text-in-python) & [Reading from file in Python, weird error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392863/reading-from-file-in-python-weird-error)

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty self explanatory. You don't have the correct destination for the file you're trying to open. Double check where it is and try again.

Comment: I guess that would be a possibility. But as is, the file is clearly in the folder shown: C:\Users\324706. I see it, and when I double-click on the file, it opens up with a simple text (the content of the file).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Peter Brittain, and others. I did that and the file is shown as test.txt.txt.